# Navigate using hector_slam

Tags: navigation, mapping, hector-navigation, move-base, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Using my custom robot base, I can successfully perform autonomous navigation using either [amcl/map_server/move_base] or [gmapping/move_base]. However, I really would like to use hector_mapping for SLAM, as it seems to perform much better (less CPU, better localization). I tried two approaches, but none led to success:

#### OPTION 1: Use hector_mapping/move_base

This fails with the follwing error message thrown by move_base:

```
[ERROR] [1384155009.792804637]: Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1384155009.754343262 but the latest data is at time 1384155009.733661973, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]
```

Looking at the output of `rosrun tf tf_monitor`, I can see the following differences between the published tf's:

hector_mapping providing /map -> /odom transform:

```
rosrun tf tf_monitor
Frame: odom published by /hector_mapping Average Delay: 0.0486663 Max Delay: 0.0770144
```

amcl providing /map -> /odom transform:

```
rosrun tf tf_monitor
Frame: odom published by /amcl Average Delay: -0.0532177 Max Delay: 0
```

This completely makes sense, as the amcl documentation states [here](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Transforms):

> The published transforms are future
> dated.

This explains why move_base throws the extrapolation error. The question is: How to fix it? Of course, I could add 0.1s to the tf time stamp generated by hector_mapping in the source, but then I won't get future package updates, which is not ideal. Any better suggestions how to make hector_mapping compatible with move_base?

#### Option 2: Use hecor_navigation package

Unfortunately, there is no documentation available for this package. As hecor_navigation only available from source, I downloaded it from [here](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_navigation) into my rosbuild workspace (package is not catkinized) and ran `rosmake` to compile it. This produced the following error:

```
[rospack] Error: package/stack 'hector_elevation_visualization' depends on non-existent package 'common_rosdeps' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
```

@Stefan: Is hecor_navigation still being maintained, or is there a successor package that is compatible with Groovy or Hydro?

Thanks,
Heiko

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99736/navigate-using-hector_slam/) by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 399 on 2013-11-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We used hector_mapping with move_base before (and some other people have done so too, I think), so things really should work. Are hector_mapping and move_base running on different machines? If that´s the case, we could be looking at a time sync issue. Other than that, it looks like some tf lookup in move_base is not done properly (i.e. a wait appears to be missing). Which move_base version are you using?

As for hector_navigation: We didn´t have time to catkinize it yet ([Atlas keeps me pretty busy these days](http://teamvigir.org/)), but we use it for our autonomous robot systems with Team Hector (also in groovy and hydro). Have you tried what happens when you remove the common_rosdeps dependency?

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on 2013-11-11**:
hector_mapping and move_base are running on the same machine, so I think we can rule time sync issues out.

**Comment by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on 2013-11-11**:
I am using the latest move_base version on Hydro, everything is up-to-date. The fact that move_base works fine if I exchange hector_mapping with amcl hints that amcl's tf future-dating is the culprit here. To confirm, I need to future-date the /map -> /odom tf provided by hector_mapping. But how?

**Comment by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on 2013-11-11**:
Btw., I have not found any reports anywhere of someone actually succeedig in usung hector_mapping as a amcl/gmapping replacement. Please provide a link if I missed soemthing.

**Comment by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on 2013-11-12**:
Regarding hector_navigation: I tried getting it to work under Hydro. Issues: 1) If I remove the common_rosdeps dependency I get ".../hector_navigation/hector_elevation_visualization/src/hector_elevation_visualization.h:16:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory"

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2013-11-12**:
I removed the old common_rosdeps dependency in package hector_elevation_visualization in https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_navigation/commit/b8515e5672132351def92db388704844c8169529 .

**Comment by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on 2013-11-12**:
Awesome, I will try it out tomorrow. Cheers!

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-11-12**:
The guy who made this video used hector_mapping with move_base apparently: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5V-0Y43i0h8 We also did so with our (LIDAR equipped) Turtlebots before.